# "session.get" получает не те данные, которые доступны по get запросу в браузере

Tags: python, python-3.x, get

начал изучение питона, разбираю этот пример: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/messages_bot/user_messages_bot.py

задумка: бот получает сообщение, ищет по тексту некую информацию и отвечает.

при первом запуске получаю отсутствие результатов поиска, докопался до того что `session.get` почему то получает не те данные, которые доступны по get запросу в браузере.

```
import sys
import requests
from inspect import getmembers
from pprint import pprint

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(
                'http://api.duckduckgo.com/',
                params={
                    'q': "машина",
                    'format': 'json'
                }
            )

print("============SESS GET============")
pprint(getmembers(response))
print("============")

sys.exit()
```

из за чего получается так что по запросу из браузера все нужные данные есть, а из питона их нет? поля просто пустые. как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Нужно значит ещё заголовки отправить может и кукисы посмотрите какие браузер отправляет заголовки.

Comment: благодарю за прекрасную наводку подсмотреть какие заголовки отправляет браузер. вставил их и всё заработало. если оформите комментарий ответом - отмечу принятым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сайт без дополнительной защиты иногда достаточно отправить заголовок

```
"User-Agent"
```

Пример:

```
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
                AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
                Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
            }
```